# Optional stopping theorem for Hilbert valued martingales

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Suppose $X_n$ is a Hilbert-valued martingale. Does the optional sampling theorem apply in this case? Does anyone know where I can find a proof?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know a reference offhand, but have you tried proving it yourself?  It seems like it should be straightforward.  If not, what goes wrong?

Comment: @NateElderedge Thank you, I agree that it should be straightforward but I am often surprised by the subtle problems appearing in infinite dimension. Thanks again!

Comment: @mellow If you're still looking for an answer, perhaps edit the question to include your attempt.